# ifstream wchar_t minGW c++

Tags: c++, mingw

I use eclipse with minGW 32.
I created a class:

```
Data(HWND hwnd,  wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH])
{
std::vector<std::string> fileRows;  
    string sIn;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(szFileName);
    infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    // fill vector with file rows
    while ( getline(infile,sIn ) )
    {
       fileRows.push_back(sIn);
    }
}
```

but the `ifstream` in MinGW could not resolve the `wchar_t`.
How can I store the file lines int the `fileRows` vector? 
Absolutely sure that the file lines are string not wstring. So I should store the lines in a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: I would avoid unicode filenames where possible.  Meanwhile, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to read text data using `wchar_t`, use [`std::wifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) to read it and [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to store it.

`std::ifstream` and `std::string` are designed specifically to use `char`.

Comment: unfortunately mingw does not supported wifstrem.

Comment: Is it possible to convecrt my wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] to char?

Comment: @CarlMark That's both surprising and correct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316962

Comment: "*Is it possible...*" Take advantage of Stack Overflow!  I could attempt an answer, but why not pose a new question to everyone?  Good luck!  :)